# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undefined filter parameter [p1]

Tags: java, hibernate-filters

I am trying to execute Hibernate Filter.

Here is my POJO class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="flight")
@FilterDef(name="f1",parameters=@ParamDef(name="status",type="String"))
@Filter(name="f1",condition="status=:p1")
public class Flight 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name="flightno")
    private int flightNumber;

    @Column(name="src", length=10)
    private String source; 

    @Column(name="dest",length=10)
    private String destination;

    @Column(name="status",length=10)
    private String status;
//setter & getters
}
```

And here is my Main class code :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
       //code for getting SessionFactory Object
        Session session=factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();

    Query query=session.createQuery("from Flight f");
    Filter filter=session.enableFilter("f1");
    filter.setParameter("p1","DELAYED");
    List list=query.list();
    Iterator itr=list.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        Flight f=(Flight)itr.next();
        System.out.println("FLIGHT NO:"+f.getFlightNumber());
        System.out.println("SOURCE :"+f.getSource());
        System.out.println("DESTINATION :"+f.getDestination());
        System.out.println("STATUS :"+f.getStatus());

        session.close();
    }
```

But i am the output like this:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Undefined filter parameter [p1]

Answer (score 15):

The error message in this case is somewhat misleading.  Hibernate is trying to tell you that the filter parameter is misconfigured.

I ran into this problem when I had a similar mapping with a Long.  The issue appears to be with the ParamDef's type definitions.  For some reason using the class name in the `type` parameter doesn't work for **L**ong and **S**tring.

It does correctly map the type if you specify it as a "primitive" by using lowercase "long" or "string"

```
@ParamDef(name="status",type="string")
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you need also modify p1 to status as u define @ParamDef(name="status",type="String")

```
@Filter(name="f1",condition="status=:status")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).